# How can I group rows that have names in different order in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, janitor

I have two data frames in R, both share a "NAME" column. I want to merge them by the NAME column, however I have the next problem:

In the DataFrame A, the names in the NAME column have this format: Anna Thompson Brown
However, in the DataFrame B some names follow the A format, but some others are like this: Thompson Brown Anna. An important note is that all names have two surnames, and some of them two names (e.g. Anna Mary Thompson Brown)

Is there a way to convert all the names to the same format? or maybe a way to merge the DataFrames even thought the names have a different order?

I haven't tried anything yet, im lost, so I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi Valeria! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example is a good one for why separating first names and last names into separate columns is usually a good idea, to avoid things like this

Comment: Essentially, you're asking to split the name column into first name and last name, when you don't know which order they are in. There's a couple of ways this could be done: 1. manually coding whether the columns are firstname(s) lastnames or vice versa, or 2. have a list of first names, and assume that if it starts with a name in the first names list, then the first name is first (and pray to god your dataset doesn't include any last names which are also first names (e.g. Alexander)

Comment: Hi, Valeria, Mark's solution is most suitable for current case, if can you somehow provide example data or at least unique values for these columns, maybe we can encode them

Comment: Can you share example data? That's the best way you can get assistance!